# PHP MySQL INSERT 1-3,000 rows as quickly and efficently as possible

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am looking for the fastest way to `INSERT` 1-3,000 rows into a MySQL database using PHP. My current solution is taking around 42 seconds to insert the rows which I think that could be much faster.

I am using a self-written DB class, the `insert()` method takes two params `(string) $table` and `(array) $vars`. The `$items` array is an associative array where the key is the column name in the table and the value is the value to insert. This works really well for because I sometimes have 30 columns in a table and already have the data there in an array. The `insert()` method is below:

```
    function insert($table,$vars) {
        if(empty($this->sql_link)){
            $this->connection();
        }
        $cols = array();
        $vals = array();
        foreach($vars as $key => $value) {
            $cols[] = "`" . $key . "`";
            $vals[] = "'" . $this->esc($value) . "'";
        }
        //join the columns and values to insert into sql
        $fields = join(', ', $cols);
        $values = join(', ', $vals);

        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($values);", $this->sql_link);
        return $insert;
}
```

It should be self-explanatory but basically I take the keys and values from $vars and create an INSERT statement. It works, I think the problem I am having is sending the queries one at a time.

Should I build a long query string?

`INSERT INTO table (field, field2, etc) VALUES (1, 2, ect);INSERT INTO table (field, field2, etc) VALUES (1, 2, ect);INSERT INTO table (field, field2, etc) VALUES (1, 2, ect);INSERT INTO table (field, field2, etc) VALUES (1, 2, ect);INSERT INTO table (field, field2, etc) VALUES (1, 2, ect);` and send it all at one time? If so can this handle 3,000 insert statements in one call?

Is there another way I am not looking at? Any info is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The most performant way is to use the multiple-row insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (field, field2, etc) VALUES (1, 2, etc),(1, 2, etc),(1, 2, etc);
```

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`
>
> The values list for each row must be enclosed within parentheses.

Comment: Added as a comment since it's anecdotal: I had the same problem on one of my sites, where I wanted to insert 50 rows at a time. Using this syntax reduced the time it took to insert all 50 by approximately 250x.

Comment: Great, this is what I meant by something I was missing! Thanks

Comment: There is no reasonable limit other than what MySQL itself can handle. For any number not measured in millions, don't worry :P

Answer (score 7):

Two ways of improve insertion speeds:

1. At the start, before any `INSERT`, do a `mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");` or a simpler `mysql_query("BEGIN");`. At the end, do a `mysql_query("COMMIT");`. These two lines, speeds up the bulk insertion a 5-10x performance.
2. If the table backend is `MyISAM` (NOT InnoDB), do the `INSERT`s followed with the word `DELAYED`. For example, instead of `INSERT INTO table` use `INSERT DELAYED INTO table` for an aditional 10-15x speed-up.

If you combine the 2 methods, is posible to achieve a speed-up of 100 times.

Comment: `+1` for the nice suggestions. Note: The `mysql_` functions are discouraged by PHP, please use `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Comment: i am parsing big xml files and making thousands of inserts. Exactly x4 speed in my case speed with START TRANSACTION on mariaDB/InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

Mysql can import data directly from a file which can significantly speed up importing data. See:

[LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = "data/fullz.txt";
$db = new PDO("sqlite:db/ssninfo.db");
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO ssninfo (fname,lname,ssn,address,city,state,zip,phone,birth,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
if($file=fopen($data, "r")){
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
        $part = explode('|', $line);
        $stmt->execute($part);
    }
}
$db->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends; you don't even mention which engine you're using, which is a big determinant. But I've found the MySQL manual guidance pretty reliable.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

**Auto discovering the maximum ammount of inserts.**

to insert that kind of ammounts (3000) there should not be any problem of doing something like (assuming you use pdo):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO yourtable(name, id) VALUES " . str_repeat('(?,?),', $amountOfRows - 1) . '(?,?)');
```

You can improve that to make create generic way to create big statements like the one above for tables with different ammount of fields:

```
$fields = array("name", "id");
$fieldList = implode(", ", $fields);
$params = '(' . str_repeat('?,', count($fields) - 1) . '?)';
$values = str_repeat($params . ',', $ammountOfRows - 1) .  $params;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $table($fieldList) VALUES " . $values);
```

but the problem with the above solution is that wont work with any combination of rows and ammount of fields.

Seems to be that mysql is not only limited by the ammount of rows but also the ammount of parameters is taken into account.

But you dont want to be changing your code whenever a new mysql release changes the limit of the parameters, rows or even the size of the sql sentence.

So, a much better approach to create a generic way to generate big statements would be trying to feat the underlaying database engine:

```
/**
 * Creates an insert sql with the maximum allowed of parameters
 * @param string $table
 * @param string $attributeList
 * @param int &$ammountInserts returns the ammount of inserts
 * @return \PDOStatement
 */
public static function getBiggestInsertStatement($table, $attributeList, $max, &$ammountInserts)
{
    $previousSize = null;
    $size = 10;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . implode(',', $attributeList) . ') values ';
    $return = null;
    $params = '(' . str_repeat('?,', count($attributeList) - 1) . '?)';

    do {
        try {
            $previousSize = $size;
            $values = str_repeat($params . ',', $size - 1) .  $params;
            $return = Db::getInstance()->prepare($sql . $values);
            if ($size > $max) {
                $values = str_repeat($params . ',', $max - 1) .  $params;
                $return = Db::getInstance()->prepare($sql . $values);
                $ammountInserts = $max;
                break;
            }
            $ammountInserts = $size;
            $size *= 2;
        } catch(\Exception $e) {

        }
    } while($previousSize != $size);

    return $return;
}
```

One thing that you must have in mind is that since you dont know that limits the query could be able to push a lower ammount of items that all that you need to insert.

So you would have to create a strategy like the one below to succesfuly achieve insert them all in any possible scenario:

```
    $insert = Db::getBiggestInsertStatement($table, array('field1','field2'), $numrows, $maximumInserts);
    $i = 0;
    $values = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < $numrows; $j++) {
        if ($i === $maximumInserts) {
            $insert->execute($values);
            $i = 0;
            $values = array();
        }
        $values[] = "value1" . $j;
        $values[] = "value2" . $j;
        $i++;
    });
    if ($i > 0) {
        $insertRemaining = Db::getBiggestInsertStatement($table, array('field1', 'field2'), $i, $maximumInserts);
        $insertRemaining->execute($values);
    }
```

I have tried to insert in a table with a single column 1000000 rows, and it's done within seconds, agains minutes that would take to insert them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

The standard technique for speeding up bulk inserts in to use a prepared SQL statement inside a loop inside a transaction. That will make it pretty well optimal. After that you could try tweaking it in various ways, but you are probably wasting your time.